# SYSLinux Error on boot, ubuntu 13.04

Tags: installation, syslinux

Want to try out Ubuntu 13.04 on my HP Pavilion dv7 1132nr but I keep getting this error.

```
SYSLINUX 4.06 EDD 2012-10-23 Copyright (C) 1994-2012 H: Peter Anvin et al
```

First of all, a few things:

1. I tried many USB installers such as Universal USB Installer, LILI, and UNetbootin, all gave me the same result
2. The drive was formatted before installation (`FAT32`).
3. The `iso` isn't corrupted, the MD5 all checked out.
4. I have another Linux Distro on this machine, would that cause this to happen?
5. The USB Drive is a Sandisk 16GB.

Hope one of you guys can fiqure this out.

Comment: found a similar, possible same, [question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/196180/not-booting-from-usb-or-cd). Problem is it seems the question hasn't been answered or had any attention for a while. Also [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/225888/question-about-12-10-32-bit-syslinux-4-06-edd-2012-10-23-usb-direct-boot)

Comment: Your not doing a wubi install by chance, are you?

Comment: No, I'm not using Wubi.

Comment: found another person with the [same issue](http://askubuntu.com/questions/287529/installing-ubuntu-13-04-desktop-amd64-using-bootable-usb-stick-failed), but they resolved it by formatting the drive fat32 then using a usb installer. You did all this and still have the problem. Does anyone else have this problem? It might be a bug. Round about solution might be to install 12.10 then upgrade the distribution to raring.

Comment: Ill try that next.

Comment: Nope, still getting this annoying screen, I'm beginning to think the USB is corrupted (its been moved around alot) or its a problem to report to theses Live USB creators. Ill try another USB later and see if that's it. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: syslinux is the bootloader on the live version of ubuntu. It's suppose to give you the option between installing and trying linux. For other people with this problem it was a missing config file caused by a small flashdrive, but in your case that can't be the problem. Is there another machine you can test to see if your flash drive will boot from? Also, [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/72696/syslinux-booting-off-a-live-usb?rq=1) implies the problem might be with hp.

Comment: the answer to [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/153603/cant-get-usb-flash-drive-to-boot?rq=1) seems to indicate using a smaller flashdrive solved the problem. Another answer I saw somewhere said sandisk usb's were the problem. So may different answers that worked for different people with the same problem...hard to tell what causes it.

Comment: Like I said, I will be buying another flash drive as I'm thinking this one is corrupted. Also I did get a Linux distro (Mint 14) to boot and install without any problems and it was using this same USB drive.